# Авторизация пользователя в iframe-приложении

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

После запуска пользователем iframe-приложения Вконтакте, на сервер приходит get-запрос от [vk.com](http://vk.com) с определенными параметрами. Как узнать что запрос пришел именно от [vk.com](http://vk.com), а не от злоумышленника?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации [описываются](https://vk.com/dev/auth_key) все get параметры, и метод, по которому проверяется `auth_key`: `auth_key = md5(api_id + '_' + viewer_id + '_' + api_secret)`.

На PHP соотв. примерно так:

```
$api_id = 123456; // номер вашего приложения
$api_secret = 'abcdefghij'; // секретный ключ приложения из Настроек
$auth_key = $_GET['auth_key'];
$viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id'];
if( $auth_key !== md5( $api_id .'_'. $viewer_id .'_'. $api_secret)) {
    die 'Малыш, это же жулики!';
}
// запрос от того viewer_id, который указан. Остальные параметры может и подделаны.
printf('<p>Здравствуй, добрый человек! Вот ты ВКонтакте: <a href="http://vk.com/id%1$d">vk.com/id%1$d</a></p>', $viewer_id);
```

Некруто, что предусмотрена верификация только параметра `viewer_id`. Остальные параметры запроса юзер может подделать. Хотя зачем ему это? =)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

[Referer](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP#.D0.9E.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8)

Comment: Его легко подменить.